# How to hide files like images and audio files and especially sqlite database from user in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

is there any way to hide files like images and audio files and especially sqlite database from user?so no can see it and access it.right now i am using document directory with .userdomainMask to store data.or can we encrypt the sqlite database?

Comment: Can you tell me how can user access this?, He can only access after jailbreaking the app.

Comment: For encrypting Sqlite, you can use sqlcipher, you can google for it

Comment: Which "user" are you referring to? Other apps? Other people using the device? ...

Comment: user means people who use the apps.and @MehulThakkar file is accessible using third party software like iexplorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide files with adding .(dot) before filename.

So, you have to rename you file like:

`mydata.sqlite`

to

`.mydata.sqlite`

Comment: does it it will be hidden if user open it will some tools?

Comment: @JayPatel probably no. If user open it using some tools it may be shown. You need to test some different-different tools for that.